# How to get the whole title which consists of several spans with XPATH?

Tags: xpath

How to get the whole title:

> Iphone case :) #phonecases#xmas#iphone#case

[image]
When the title does not include hashtags I can get all the title with this xpath:

```
((//*[@class='pinWrapper'])[2]//span)[1]/text()
```

This line:

```
((//*[@class='pinWrapper'])[2]//span)[1]//text()[normalize-space()]
```

returns only the first one: `Iphone case :)`.

And this:

```
((//*[@class='pinWrapper'])[2]//span)[1][string()]
```

returns whole xml:

```
<span>Iphone case :) <a href="/search/pins/?q=%23phonecases&amp;rs=hashtag_pinrep" rel=""><span class="pinHashtag">#phonecases</span></a> <a href="/search/pins/?q=%23xmas&amp;rs=hashtag_pinrep" rel=""><span class="pinHashtag">#xmas</span></a> <a href="/search/pins/?q=%23iphone&amp;rs=hashtag_pinrep" rel=""><span class="pinHashtag">#iphone</span></a> <a href="/search/pins/?q=%23case&amp;rs=hashtag_pinrep" rel=""><span class="pinHashtag">#case</span></a></span>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `((//*[@class='pinWrapper'])[2]//span)[1]/text()` returns you *first text node only*, try

```
string(((//*[@class='pinWrapper'])[2]//span)[1])
```

to get complete string

Comment: @F.Vosnim , on picture it's not my XPath. Where did you get it from?

Comment: I added your `string( 'object' )` to the same xpath.

Comment: @F.Vosnim , why? :) You should do this like `string(//span)`, but not like `string((//span/text())[1])`. You've used `string` incorrectly. Can you share URL for the same? Also you should not try it in Chrome devtools - try directly in code

Comment: Your XPath: https://i.imgur.com/8BjRRSB.png This is exactly your line. I don't understand what I do wrong.

Comment: @F.Vosnim , `string` doesn't return node, so it won't be found in Chrome dev console. Try it in code

Comment: @F.Vosnim, not in Chrome. You're using some programming language with scraping tool, right? How do you want to use this XPath?

Comment: Usually I get XPath xml value and then use it in javascript code. But when XPath finds nothing it returns "undefined". How can I use `string("undefined")` in javascript?

Comment: @F.Vosnim , it's not `undefined`. You will get string presentation from found node. Try it in code. If it won't work - share your JS code

Comment: I see an error message: `Can't resolve query string(((//*[@class='pinWrapper'])[2]//span)[1])` https://i.imgur.com/7EoF7jM.png

Comment: @F.Vosnim I'm not familiar wit `html_parse_xpath_exist` function, so I don't know why it raised an exception... Maybe your parser has some attributes, like `text` or `toString` so you can use it to extract string value?

Comment: `html_parse_xpath_exist` returns `false` because it can't find xpath like `string(((//...)[1])` (as I told above). Do you know how to get the title using `normalize-space` or something like that?

Comment: @F.Vosnim , XPath is not something that *can be found* but an expression that returns different type of data. It might be an element, text node, boolean, string... If your function intend to return node, then it also won't work with `normalize-space` (that retuirns string also). XPath is correct, but your function might just "don't know" how to handle such XPath expression

Comment: Everything that finds element in Chrome devtools works great. I used some `normalize-space` xpath lines and they also worked fine.But I'm not very good at xpath syintax for `normalize-space`.